Современные процессоры Intel (Intel Core Ultra 3, 5, 7, 9) имеют Гарвардскую или фон Неймановскую архитектуру?
Столкнулся с проблемой, что требуется узнать, какая архитектура используется для этих процессоров.
Это Гарвардская (Расширенная/Модифицированная) или фон Неймановская?
Если гибридная, то как именно? (поясню, что имею в виду: например, L1-кэш имеет разделение на данные и инструкции, т.е Гарвардскую архитектуру, а всё остальное фон Неймановское. В этом суть гибридной архитектуры для Intel Core i5-4300U (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558834/how-can-i-tell-whether-my-computer-is-harvard-or-von-neumann-architecture))

А что вам это дает в практическом плане? Даже если будете программировать чистое железо (без ОС). Можете считать гибридной (или фон Неймановской). Если не брать программно невидимый (в смысле исполнения инструкций кэш), то фон Неймановская при определенной настройке MMU, а при другой (кстати, когда работает под ОС, то она всегда такая) Гарвардской (вы же не можете просто так исполнять данные как команды процессра)

@avp Ничего в практическом плане не даёт. Но в теоретическом такая информация понадобилась. Информацию нашёл только по другим процам (вышеупомянутый i5-4300U), но интересуют актуальные на данный момент модели.

Да это было всё до эпохи Meltdown.

но интересуют актуальные на данный момент модели

Актуальные модели имеют такие технологии в архитектуре памяти:

Intel® Trusted Execution Technology

Intel® Total Memory Encryption - Multi Key


Некоторые потребительские процессоры обладали технологией полного гомоморфного шифрования Intel SGX.
Не думаю, что память где-то используется с прямым доступом к данным.

Информацию нашёл только по другим процам

Официальной информации на сайте Intel достаточно, чтобы ответить на любые связанные с управлением памятью вопросы.

Учтите, ваша ссылка в Intel на территории РФ выдает "Мы немедленно приостановили все деловые операции в России. Это следует за нашим предыдущим решением приостановить все поставки клиентам в России и Беларуси."

@avp эта заглушка стоит не первый день, уже как 2.5 года.

Тогда зачем вы даете эту ссылку на этом сайте?

@avp Если вам нужно узнать про внутренне строение процессоров Intel, то официальный сайт Intel всегда был и остается кладезью ценной информации, несмотря на то, хотят они работать с клиентами из РФ и РБ.
